# Print out only the version of Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, echo, version

I need to echo only the version of Ubuntu in BASH. So let's say that I am on Ubuntu Trusty (14.04), I want to be able to print out just the `14.04` part.

Comment: Why not have a look at [\[ askubuntu \]](http://askubuntu.com)?

Comment: Oops, my bad.. I'm used to stackoverflow that I forgot about askubuntu..

Comment: @sjsam Please also consider looking for duplicates on SO; many questions have old answers, even though they are off-topic (maybe they weren't at the time, or maybe we didn't notice back then, and they remained open).  Closing as duplicate is less effort because a gold badge owner can single-handledly close.  (Also, more tangentially, `[ubuntu.se]` is available as a Markdown shortcut: [ubuntu.se].)

Comment: @tripleee : Agree with you, will keep this in mind. :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is `lsb_release -sr`.

For example, on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine:

```
$ lsb_release -sr
16.04
```

Comment: Ah, much simpler than my solution!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following:

```
head -2 /etc/lsb-release | tail -1 | cut -f 2 -d '='
```

Which prints out: `14.04`